# Jumping in Artificial Gravity equals Thrust?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

What would append if a human jumped while in a rotating ring ? From what I can imagine, the jump would induce a force that would propel the ring in one direction, but as the human has now both a vertical and forward speed (from an external reference point), he would land ahead of it's original position (from the ring reference) propelling the ring even further at a slight angle from the first thrust.
But according to Newton's, the ring shouldn't move in space as no matter has been ejected.
So where does the thrust in the opposite direction comes from ?

[image]

Comment: You changed frame of reference halfway through your argument. Maintain the idea that the human travels in a straight line after they jump and until they meet the ring again.

Comment: Even when not changing the frame of reference, I think I miss one of the accelerations. Can you tell me the ones I forget one the following image ?
https://imgur.com/a/kwj1a

Comment: Both of your acceleration vectors are wrong. Since his momentum is down and to the right, the acceleration on the wheel must be (by Newton's Third Law), up and to the left for jumping and down and to the right for landing.

Comment: How does he accelerates to the right ? He just keeps his momentum to the right.

Comment: Picture included here. Differentiated acceleration of Man and of Ring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the man is on the ring surface a centripedal force is applied to him, causing him to move in a circle. (This is not shown on your diagram)

When the man is not in contact with the ring this force is not applied to him, and he moves in a straight line. During this period the force required to maintain the circular motion of that part of the ring, now unencumbered by the man's mass, is reduced. However, the force required to achieve circular motion on the opposite side of the ring is unchanged. As these forces do not balance, the ring will accelerate, (denoted by $\alpha$).

$\alpha$ is equal and opposite to the acceleration of the ring depicted on your diagram.

Another way to look at this is that when the man is not in contact with the ring, the center of mass of the rotating part of the system has moved. The ring "under" the man takes a larger arc, and on the opposite side a smaller arc.

[image]

Comment: So if you have a rotating ring with an object in it and you open the floor under that object, the ring would be propelled in the opposite direction ?

Comment: Yes. If a body ejects mass, it will be propelled in the opposite direction. Also the center of mass would move and it would start to rotate differently.

Comment: (I mean it would also start to rotate about a different center of mass.)